# Why is $\frac1h\int_0^t\left(T(s+h)-T(s)\right)x\;{\rm d}s=\frac1h\int_t^{t+h}T(s)x\;{\rm d}s-\frac1h\int_0^hT(s)x\;{\rm d}s$ for a semigroup $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, riemann-integration, semigroup-of-operators

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $T:[0,\infty)\to\mathfrak L(E)$ be a $C^0$-semigroup, i.e.

1. $T(0)=\text{id}_E$
2. $T(s+t)=T(s)T(t)$ for all $s,t\ge 0$
3. $[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto T(t)x$ is continuous for all $x\in E$

I don't understand why $$\frac1h\int_0^t\left(T(s+h)-T(s)\right)x\;{\rm d}s=\frac1h\int_t^{t+h}T(s)x\;{\rm d}s-\frac1h\int_0^hT(s)x\;{\rm d}s\tag 1$$ for all $t,h>0$ and $x\in E$. I guess it's simply an application of the substitution rule, but I don't see why the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ has $h$ (and not $t$) as the upper limit.

Comment: You rarely upvote answers to your questions, don't you? Note that upvoting and accepting an answer is the appropriate way to say "Thank you for answering my question."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} \int_0^t (T(s+h)-T(s))x \, ds &= \int_h^{t+h} T(s) x \, ds - \int_0^t T(s) x \, ds \\ &= \int_t^{t+h} T(s) \, x \, ds - \int_0^h T(s) x \, ds.\end{align*}$$